# Returning false in beforeDelete callback kills deleteAll

Tags: cakephp

When deleting a record, I'm testing to see if a condition is true or false, and based on the result, procede with the deletion or return from it.

The problem is that "return false" stops deleteAll completely. My understanding was that deleteAll would simply move along to the next record.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: return false is likely to stop any code, but it would be a lot easier to tell you exactly if you post some code.

Comment: Please, 1) add some code, 2) debug the variable before the callback and 3) post the error

Answer (score 2):

The `beforeDelete` method allows you to abort a delete operation if something seems off. By having it return false, you abort the action. In this case, the deleteAll action, meaning you abort *all* the deletes. What you're more likely looking for is deleting in a foreach loop, like:

```
// $data would be the resultset of the rows you want to delete
foreach($data as $row) {
    $this->Model->delete($row['Model']['id']);
}
```

That way, the `beforeDelete` is called for each row individually, allowing "valid" rows to be deleted and "invalid" rows to be kept.

Comment: I thought as much. I assumed deleteAll ran as a loop, and that returning false would kill deletion for the current record, no everything in the queue. Thanks!